# How to add multiple Textfields in single or multiple pages in a Loop

Tags: spring-boot, itext

I am Using Itext 5 maven and I want to add multiple textfields in multiple pdf pages. like page 1 need 3 fields, page 2 need 4 fields etc.

I have write the below code

```
public byte[] setupDocument(EditPdfDTO editPdfDTOList, MultipartFile attachment)
{

    WritePDF obj = new WritePDF();

    Document document = null;
    PdfWriter writer = null;
    PdfImportedPage page = null;
    PdfReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        // Create output PDF
        document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        document.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream("D:/test.pdf"));

        document.open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

        // Load existing PDF
        reader = new PdfReader(attachment.getBytes());

        int totalPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        for (int i = 0; i < totalPages; i++)
        {
            page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i + 1);
            document.newPage();
            cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);

            for (int j = 0; j < editPdfDTOList.getPdf().size(); j++)
            {
                if (i + 1 == editPdfDTOList.getPdf().get(j).getPageNo())
                {
                    BaseFont baseFont = null;
                    try
                    {
                        baseFont = BaseFont.createFont();
                    }
                    catch (DocumentException | IOException e1)
                    {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    int a, b;
                    a = editPdfDTOList.getPdf().get(j).getxCoordinate();
                    b = editPdfDTOList.getPdf().get(j).getyCoordinate();

                    String str = editPdfDTOList.getPdf().get(j).getTextContent();

                    Rectangle linkLocation =
                            new Rectangle(a, b + baseFont.getDescentPoint(str, 10),
                                    a + 10 + baseFont.getWidthPoint(str, 10),
                                    b + baseFont.getAscentPoint(str, 10) + 10);
                    TextField field =
                            new TextField(writer, linkLocation, "user1" + j+UUID.randomUUID());

                    field.setFontSize(10);
                    field.setOptions(TextField.MULTILINE | TextField.READ_ONLY);
                    field.setTextColor(BaseColor.RED);
                    field.setText(str);
                    field.setBorderWidth(1);

                    cb = writer.getDirectContent();

                    try
                    {
                        cb.addAnnotation(field.getTextField(),false);
                    }
                    catch (IOException | DocumentException e)
                    {
                         e.printStackTrace();           
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (DocumentException | IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        document.close();

    }
    return null;
}
```

this code is able to add only one Textfield on every expected but not to add 2 or many textfields in a single page.

there is no issue of multiple try--catch block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The appropriate classes to use

First of, you say you *"want to add multiple textfields in multiple pdf pages"*. When implementing tasks like this, i.e. tasks that take a single document and want to somehow manipulate it while keeping it structurally more or less as before, one should usually work with a `PdfReader`/`PdfStamper` couple. This allows you to concentrate on the manipulation and provides a copy of the original PDF with all its properties to work on.

## Adding multiple fields to a page of an existing PDF

Adding multiple fields to a single existing page is trivial, e.g.:

```java
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(resource);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, output);

TextField field1 = new TextField(pdfStamper.getWriter(),
                                 new Rectangle(100, 800, 200, 820), "Field1");
field1.setBorderColor(BaseColor.CYAN);
field1.setBorderStyle(PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_DASHED);
field1.setBorderWidth(BaseField.BORDER_WIDTH_MEDIUM);
field1.setText("Field 1");
pdfStamper.addAnnotation(field1.getTextField(), 1);

TextField field2 = new TextField(pdfStamper.getWriter(),
                                 new Rectangle(300, 800, 400, 820), "Field2");
field2.setBorderColor(BaseColor.RED);
field2.setBorderStyle(PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_INSET);
field2.setBorderWidth(BaseField.BORDER_WIDTH_THIN);
field2.setText("Field 2");
pdfStamper.addAnnotation(field2.getTextField(), 1);

pdfStamper.close();
```

*([AddField](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/form/AddField.java#L287) test `testAddMultipleFields`)*

Applied to my example document

[image: screen shot original]

the code generates

[image: screen shot result]

Thus, there is no conceptual problem adding multiple text fields to the same document page, it works in a very natural manner.

In your case I would switch to using a `PdfReader`/`PdfStamper` couple. If some issue still remain, I would inspect your data. Probably they simply contain only a single field dataset per page. Or two textfields have the same coordinates and, therefore, look like one. Or some text fields have off-screen coordinates. Or... Or... Or...

## The original answer

*Originally the code in the question looked differently. This original answer focused on issues of that code.*

You claim your code

> is able to add only one Textfield on every expected but not to add 2 or many textfields in a single page

I doubt that because

1. you have two distinct objects writing to the same file `"D:/TemplateFilePDf/" + attachment.getOriginalFilename()` concurrently, the `PdfWriter writer` and the `PdfStamper stamper`. If you get something sensible as a result of your code, then only by pure luck; and
2. additionally `stamper` is instantiated for a `null` instance of `PdfReader`. This actually will cause a `NullPointerException` in the constructor which will keep your textfield adding code from being executed at all.

Thus, either the code you shared is considerably different from the code you run or your test runs actually all throw that `NullPointerException` and you probably find the outputs of a former, less broken version of your code which happens to have added only a single text field.

After fixing those two issues, some questions still remain (e.g. what is the intention of that `cb.fill()`? That instruction is only allowed directly after a path definition, the path whose inner area to fill, but I don't see you defining any path).

Furthermore, you access your `editPdfDTOList` for a lot of relevant values but we don't know those values. Thus, we cannot run your code to try and reproduce the issue. Probably you create only a single textfield because that object contains only values for a single textfield...

Comment: Yes you are right, but stamper I have not used anywhere. Do you have any idea how to add multiple textfields in one or many pages or any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @Deva *"Do you have any idea how to add multiple textfields in one or many pages"* - I updated my answer to focus on that aspect of your question.

Comment: Yes, I dont have any doubt that your answer is correct but I wanted to add Textfield in a loop, not by creating different objects of textfields. I also updated my question.

Comment: @Deva *"I wanted to add Textfield in a loop, not by creating different objects of textfields."* - Obviously. And now that I showed that it works in principle, you merely have to build that into a loop. That's plain Java 101.